# Storing and Querying key/value (UUID) with a Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Our Jenkins instance submits jobs to a batch system (slurm) for execution of individual tasks. A single jenkins job might submit a few thousand batch jobs and we need a unique way to correlate all these batch jobs to the original jenkins job.

I'm currently generating a UUID in our groovy script and setting that in the environment so it gets picked up by slurm and logged in slurm's accounting database. I'd like to also store the UUID with the Jenkins job so we can query Jenkins for the UUID.

Using other identifiers (e.g. the Jenkins ID) isn't ideal because there may be overlap in IDs among jobs from different pipelines, and also unnecessarily couples our batch and CI system; a UUID seems to be a more generic option.

Is there a way in Jenkins, preferably from a groovy script, to store an arbitrary key/value with a job along with some way to query jenkins for that key/value to get back to the job?